# How do I make an animation using HTML5 and CSS3? Are there free apps to do it?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'd like to put an animation in a web page using HTML5 and CSS3. Are there free apps that help to do that?

Comment: What kind of animation, what have you tried? And to answer you question: Yes there are some tools.

Comment: which tools? could you say?

Comment: that would depend in what kind of animations you want. Animate Text or images?

Comment: I've been thinking about making my own drawings and joining all of them like an animated cartoon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some really great tutorials out there. Have you tried Google yet?

I found this one particularly useful: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

See also:
* http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/14/the-guide-to-css-animation-principles-and-examples/
* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations
* http://cferdinandi.github.io/spinners/